# Matlab marketdepth to be use in Simulink inflow with custom M function for callback to reside in Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, callback, simulink

I am not sure if this capability exists either in Matlab or Simulink.
I am trying to use the Matlab Datafeed toolbox function:

```
 iqf.marketdepth
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/iqf.marketdepth.html
If i use the example of:

```
 marketdepth(q,'ABC',@iqfeedmarketdepthlistener,@iqfeedmarketdeptheventhandler
```

Is there a way I can use this above example as a Simulink inflow custom M function block? I would then like to use the iqfeedmarketdeptheventhandler function to reside within a Simulink block or Simulink model. Can the handler function be a custom M function block within a Simulink model? Can this even be done?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not the handler function itself, but there is a block called Embedded matlab colde in simulink where you can write functions as in .m files. try to create one and play with it so it can use your user defined function inside. Not sure about the limitations of the embedded matlab code block tough

Comment: I meant to say my custom M function would be the same as Embedded Matlab code block. I guess I am still back to the original question. Thanks anyhow

Comment: I am sorry I cant help you more!